# About LaTeX for a beginner

Tags: errors

Hullo, Im just starting up with LaTeX. I keep getting error messages even though I feel as though everything has been done correctly. I am just doing the intro exercise which is shown from the help tab from my MikTeX install. I am getting errors like article.cls not found.
Can I download a LaTeX editor from somewhere, or is the MikTeX which I installed mising some files.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: We need more information...

Comment: Without further informations, maybe a look at this: (Manually install a Package on Miktex)[http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows]  can help you.

Comment: If the compiler does not find the article-class, you have not installed MikTeX correctly. Search your computer for the file article.cls. If you find the file, try to updated the file database (run MikTeX configure).